# Why does C++ stringstream skip the first byte when I read a file

Tags: c++, io, fstream, stringstream

My code is like this:

```
   using namespace std;

    string pth("./xxx.pb");
    ifstream fin(pth, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    int len = fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg(0);

    cout << "compare:\n";
    string s1(len, 0);
    fin.read(&s1[0], len);
    for (auto &el : s1)
        cout << (int)el << ", ";
    cout << endl;

    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0);
    stringstream ss;
    fin >> ss.rdbuf();
    for (auto &el : ss.str())
        cout << (int)el << ", ";
    cout << endl;
```

The output is like this:

```
compare:
10, 5, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 18, 2, 4, 6, 26, 7, 102, 108, 111, 97, 116, 51, 50, 32, 3, 
5, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 18, 2, 4, 6, 26, 7, 102, 108, 111, 97, 116, 51, 50, 32, 3,
```

It seems that the stringstream skipped the first byte when it read from the file. Where does my problem come from?

Comment: Check out [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws)

Comment: @paddy How could I add this to my code since I am not using `>>` ?

Comment: I don't understand.  You _are_ the person who wrote `fin >> ss.rdbuf()`, right?  So it would become `fin >> std::noskipws >> ss.rdbuf()`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have solved the problem as you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fin >>` to input a string will skip leading white space. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt):

> Behaves as a `FormattedInputFunction`. After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, ...

So the line feed character (whose ASCII is 10) in the beginning of your file is skipped.